# Firebase child_removed not being called

Tags: firebase

This is the basic idea of my code. I removed a lot of extra stuff from my actual code, but it was mostly css - none of it should have any affect on this...

```
listRef.on('child_removed', function(childSnapshot, prevChildName) {
    alert('child removed!');
});

listRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildName) {
    itemRef = childSnapshot.ref();

    alert('child added!);

    itemRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
        alert('item value changed!');

        var name = snapshot.val().name;  // if I remove this line, child_removed is called
        $("#name").html(name);
    });
});

$("#button").click(function() {
    itemRef.remove();
});
```

The problem is that on `$("#button")` click, itemRef is removed from listRef in Firebase, but the `'child_removed'` event is never triggered... If I take out

```
driveRef = undefined;
```

then `child_removed` is called...

Everything else works - `$("#name")` is updated and all of the `alert()` dialogs I am using to test it are working fine - the only problem is `child_removed` not being called.

Comment: `driveRef = undefined` doesn't appear in your sample code; I assume that's a bad copy/paste. However, the line you commented uses snapshot.val().name, but snapshot.val() may be null!

Comment: Thanks Kato, I didn't realize itemRef.on() would be called when the item is removed...

Comment: Right, and in case you didn't deduce this from Mr. Lehenbauer's answer, my interpretation is that when `on('value', ...)` is invoked, it gets treated like a lookup and called with `null` if the record doesn't exist (more on this in the docs); from this point on, it behaves like the listener it seems to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Kato's comment is right on.  If you look in your browser dev tools javascript console, or better yet set it to break on all exceptions (e.g. [directions for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_exceptions)), I bet you'll find your 'value' callback is being called with snapshot.val() == null when the child is removed, and so your code throws an exception which is preventing Firebase from raising further events (i.e. your child_removed event).

We have some feature work planned to make Firebase a little more tolerant of event callbacks throwing exceptions, but for now the fix is to check for snapshot.val() == null in your 'value' callback.